# How do I solve the linear programming relaxed MKP?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, computer-science, linear-programming, knapsack-problem

I am studying about Knapsack problem. So I do not understand one thing here.

The profit/pseudo-resource consumption ratios

> U<sub>j</sub> = P<sub>j</sub> / W<sub>j</sub> with W<sub>j</sub> = R<sub>ji</sub> * A<sub>j</sub>

I hope so you people know this equation thus I think no need more explanation.
I wanted to calculate Aj here. What is that LP relaxation . How they are calculating using total capacity and weight (size of item). If i have n item and m capacity it means i should  to have  m LP relaxation variable. Is it right ?

Some one saying like

One of the simplest methods to obtain reasonably good multipliers is to solve the linear programming (LP) relaxed MKP in which the variables x<sub>j</sub> may get arbitrary values from the interval [0, 1] and to use the values of the dual variables as the surrogate multipliers.
In other words, a<sub>j</sub> is set to the shadow price of the jth constraint in the LP relaxed MKP.

How they are calculating shadow price of jth constraint in the LP relaxed MKP. I am searching from Google for while but there is not so much clear. Does anyone know to understand by easy way?

Thank you to read until here :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what is the core question here. If what you're really asking is "what is a relaxed KP", then you can refer to your own other question which I just answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128001/linear-programming-relaxed-for-mkp

Comment: define your variables please.