# linear programming relaxed for MKP

Tags: knapsack-problem

how to calculate to find this relaxation. What should i know to find it. Suppose i have n items and m knapsack . So i wanted to know the number of m relaxation. Does anybody can give me some idea at least. I have been searching it for while. There is some article on internet but not much clear. Please at least someone say to me you should read this thing , you should know this thing e.i so i will very appreciate

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think your real question is "what is the exact definition of a Linear-Relaxed Knapsack Problem?", so I'm going to answer assuming it is.

The short answer is that **a *linear-relaxed* KP is the fractionary version of a 0-1 KP [1]**.

Mathemathically, all you have to do is to convert the restriction "x_i belongs to the {0, 1} set" and convert it to "x_i must be any real number between 0 and 1", where x_i is the quantity of the i-th item in your solution backpack.

The name comes from the fact that the 0-1 KP is an integer programming problem. The 'linear' term means that the solution variables can assume continuous values.

Not all relaxations are linear, though. You might want to check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_%28approximation%29#Some_relaxation_techniques) Wikipedia page for them.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming_relaxation